# Simple question about package : why it doesn't work?

Tags: packages

My notebook can't load my package and I don't know why.

I called "testons.m" the file containing my package, I wrote inside it the following exemple code :

```
BeginPackage[ "Package`"]



MainFunction::usage = 
    "MainFunction[ x] computes a simple function."

  Begin[ "Private`"]

  MainFunction[ x_] :=
    Module[ {y},
      y = x^2;
      y + 1
    ]

  End[]

  EndPackage[]
```

I put it in the folder :`C:\Users\Me\Dropbox\internship-2017\Mathematica\initialisation`

I wrote in my working notebook :

```
AppendTo[$Path,
"C:\\Users\\Me\\Dropbox\\internship-2017\\Mathematica\\initialisation"]
```

And when I write later in the same notebook :

```
<< Package`
```

Mathematica answers me : "Get::noopen: Cannot open Package`."

I followed the exact instruction written here : https://reference.wolfram.com/workbench/index.jsp?topic=/com.wolfram.eclipse.help/html/tasks/applications/packages.html

Where is my mistake ?

Thanks

Comment: Try using another name for your package, because ``Package` `` context already reserved by Mathematica itself.

Comment: I did it but it does'nt solve the problem with another name. Few questions in the same time : Must the name of the package file be the same as the name of the package inside ? If I modify something inside the package file do I have to do a "refresh" in my notebook ? And can the folder names contains space or accents ?

Comment: Also see the third answer from the end here: http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/879149 about ``"Private`"`` vs ``"`Private`"``

Comment: Did you create the file as a package from the beginning? It seems that a package is more than a notebook with .wl or .m extension - it appears that you must always open the notebook's File menu, select New, and choose Package.

Comment: @StarBucK I think you should call your package by its file name, not context name, so in your case `<<"Testons`"` . Package context can be different from its file name, but I think this is not good practice.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers, I summarized what I understood with your help (with some extras) in the answer below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to the comments above I have solved the problem. I think it would be nice to summarise how to avoid it.

First :

We have to add the **folder** where the package is in the $Path variable. This folder can contain spaces in its name without problem.

We have to save a package as a package file in mathematica (.wl in the menu).
The package filename cannot contain "_" (maybe other special letters wont work as well).

To ensure that the functions of the package are loaded, its cells has to be put as initialization cells : menu "cell->cell properties->initialization cell".

Next :

The package is called by its **filename** not by the string between BeginPackage["thestring`"] in the packagefile. Do not forget the "`", even if we are talking about the filename. For example if the package filename is "test.wl", we have to call it by writing : << test`

The package filename and the package name (the thing we write inside the bracket of BeginPackage) **can** be different.

After each modifications of package file, we have to load again the package to take in account thoose modifications.

Comment: Let's call the package `mypack`. Especially if you're going to include separate documentation files (always a good idea!), a good practice is to put the mpack`.m` (or `mypack.wl`) package file in a subfolder, also named `mypack`, of your UserBaseDirectory. And then inside that create a `Kernel` subfolder and in that place an `init.m` file whose sole contents, as an initialization cell, is: `Get["mypack\`mypack\`"]`.

Comment: Thanks. This also works in Wolfram Cloud